Allow docker container to connect with tunnelled aws redshift
Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?
My current scenario:
I'm using docker desktop in my windows machine. On this docker desktop, I use the Ubuntu as the operating machine.
Now, I perform tunneling to AWS redshift and it successfully connected. I could also use dBeaver to view all the database on that aws redshift.
Now, I wanted to run some query using the sqlalchemy that is inside my docker container. Using all the same credentials that I entered in dBeaver, I'm somehow facing this error:
Connection refused.

Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP Connections?

Do you have any idea how can I allow the docker container to access aws redshift being tunneled in my docker desktop?
Thank youuu
At first, tunnelling was set up in the windows machine, but I transferred it later on inside docker desktop hoping it could somehow solve the isssue

You don't show how you create the tunnel, but by default ssh -L binds to localhost. But that's not accessible from within a Docker container. You need to bind to a specific local IP address and use that address from within the container.

Expose the needed (used) ports in your containers.
